# Restangular TypeError: Cannot set property 'route' of null

Tags: angularjs, restangular

This is a Angular function that previously worked...

```
    $scope.InsertLabelText = function () {

    var MapText = $("#txtMapLabel").val();
    Restangular.setBaseUrl(BaseURL);

    if (MapText != null) {
        //Call WebAPI to enter text then refresh map.


        var TextObjs = Restangular.all('PostObjects');
        NewTextObject = {TypeMapId: "5", GrowerId: $("#GrowerName").val(), CropYear: $("#CropYear").val(), NAME: MapText, SHAPE: coordinates}

        TextObjs.getList(NewTextObject).then(function (data) {
            $scope.Label = data;
            if ($scope.Label.Success = true) {

                var geojson_format = new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON();
                var Object_style = OpenLayers.Util.extend({}, layer_style);
                Object_style.fillOpacity = 0.7;
                Object_style.label = MapText;
                Object_style.graphicZIndex = 4999;
                Text.style = Object_style;
                Text.addFeatures(geojson_format.read($scope.Label.TextObject));

                LabelLine.destroyFeatures();
            }
            else {
                console.log(data);
                var Error = prompt($scope.Label.TextObject);
                console.log("There was an error saving");
            }
            $("#divMapInputText").hide();
        });


    }

};
```

It fails on the call TextObjs.getList with the error "TypeError: Cannot set property 'route' of null"

I have 3 other functions in the same controller with the same code pattern but they all work?

Here is the whole error from chrome...

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'route' of null
at g (http://localhost/FarmMapsMvc4/Scripts/ThirdParty/restangular.min.js:8:8705)
at t (http://localhost/FarmMapsMvc4/Scripts/ThirdParty/restangular.min.js:8:11154)
at http://localhost/FarmMapsMvc4/Scripts/ThirdParty/restangular.min.js:8:13225
at http://localhost/FarmMapsMvc4/Scripts/ThirdParty/lodash.min.js:72:226
at y (http://localhost/FarmMapsMvc4/Scripts/ThirdParty/lodash.min.js:16:110)
at Function.Et (http://localhost/FarmMapsMvc4/Scripts/ThirdParty/lodash.min.js:72:191)
at http://localhost/FarmMapsMvc4/Scripts/ThirdParty/restangular.min.js:8:13149
at h (http://localhost/FarmMapsMvc4/Scripts/ThirdParty/angular.min.js:78:33)
at http://localhost/FarmMapsMvc4/Scripts/ThirdParty/angular.min.js:78:266
at Object.e.$eval (http://localhost/FarmMapsMvc4/Scripts/ThirdParty/angular.min.js:88:347) angular.min.js:62(anonymous function) angular.min.js:62(anonymous function) angular.min.js:52h angular.min.js:78(anonymous function) angular.min.js:78e.$eval angular.min.js:88e.$digest angular.min.js:86e.$apply angular.min.js:88e angular.min.js:95p angular.min.js:98t.onreadystatechange
```

Comment: Where is `coordinates` variable initiated?

Comment: Coordinates is declared as a controller level variable and populated in another angular function when the user clicks.

Comment: It should be working. I don't see anything wrong. If you debug Restangular's code, where do you see the problem? If you add a `responseInterceptor` and debug it there, is there data returned from the server? Beucase that error seems that you cannot set a field to an undefined value which is probably coming from the server